# [role]s are not contained by their required parent element

Tags: tabulator

I keep getting this warning,  its specifically on the columnheaders and appears not only in my table but in other tables that I look at, as there an fix for this?  Something to do with Aria parent and child but I'm not sure

this shows the role="columnheader"  but its still throwing the warning:
[image]

Comment: Per ARIA recommendation, elements with role `columnheader` must be contained in, or owned by, an element with the role `row` (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#columnheader)  Since the parent `row` element is missing, you get the warning.

Comment: how do i fix this in tabulator then?

Comment: You will need to ask the author of Tabulator for the fix I am afraid.  Btw, looks like v5.0 has already fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim points out, this was an issue in an old version of Tabulator, as of version 5.0 this is no longer an issue